# JavaScript test on V8

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function add(x, y) {  
   return x + y;  
}  

console.time("time1");

for (var i = 0; i < 90000000; ++i) {
    add(1, 2);   
    add('a','b');
}

console.timeEnd("time1");

function addText(x, y) {   
   return x + y;  
} 

function addNumber(x, y) {   
   return x + y;  
}

console.time("time2");

for (var i = 0; i < 90000000; ++i) {
    addNumber(1, 2);   
    addText('a','b');
}

console.timeEnd("time2");
```

the result is:
time1: 1481ms,
time2: 102ms,

i running this test on nodejs, but i don't know why the first test run slower than the second one.

Comment: @Matt Ball: I swapped - it's the same. http://jsfiddle.net/6G9aa/

Comment: Let's do this right, shall we? http://jsperf.com/so-q20039587

Comment: It sure looks like when you call a function in V8 it can re-use the previous call's generated code if the data types of the parameters are the same as the previous call.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I think it's mostly checks by V8 for different types and being unable to optimise for specific types which slow down the code signficantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of deoptimisation happening under the hood due to parameter type change. To know this, we have to know what optimsiation V8 does:

#### Inlining

It is an important optimisation and is crucial for performance boost. It replaces function call with function body to speedup execution. If a function is small in size it will be inlined. This assumes that in function calls, the parameters are fixed.

#### Deoptimisation

The V8 does optimisation under certain assumptions. If it is wrong it has to undo those optimisations,so that it is able to run code correctly. Deoptimizations are bad because it takes time and the replaced code is less-performant.

To see this in action run the code with options  `--trace_opt` `--trace_opt_stats` `--trace_deopt` `--trace-inlining`

```
[deoptimize context: cbf30f14679]
[marking addText 0xcbf30fc5ca0 for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 1/1 (100%)]
[optimizing: addText / cbf30fc5ca1 - took 0.058, 0.092, 0.000 ms]
Compiled: 1 functions with 42 byte source size in 0.150000ms.
[marking addNumber 0xcbf30fc5ce8 for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 1/1 (100%)]
[optimizing: addNumber / cbf30fc5ce9 - took 0.019, 0.033, 0.000 ms]
Compiled: 2 functions with 84 byte source size in 0.202000ms.
[marking  0x2c9408e1b3d0 for recompilation, reason: not much type info but very hot, ICs with typeinfo: 1/12 (8%)]
Inlined addNumber called from .
Inlined addText called from .
[optimizing:  / 2c9408e1b3d1 - took 0.131, 0.229, 0.000 ms]
Compiled: 3 functions with 898 byte source size in 0.562000ms.
time1: 126ms
**** DEOPT:  at bailout #11, address 0x0, frame size 192
[deoptimizing: begin 0x2c9408e1b3d1  @11]
  translating  => node=111, height=32
    0x7fff72081080: [top + 104] <- 0x2c9408e1b4e9 ; [sp + 32] 0x2c9408e1b4e9 <an Object>
    0x7fff72081078: [top + 96] <- 0x58df1704121 <undefined> ; literal
    0x7fff72081070: [top + 88] <- 0x58df1704121 <undefined> ; literal
    0x7fff72081068: [top + 80] <- 0x58df1704121 <undefined> ; literal
    0x7fff72081060: [top + 72] <- 0x58df1704121 <undefined> ; literal
    0x7fff72081058: [top + 64] <- 0x58df1704121 <undefined> ; literal
    0x7fff72081050: [top + 56] <- 0x23522b3122be ; caller's pc
    0x7fff72081048: [top + 48] <- 0x7fff720810b0 ; caller's fp
    0x7fff72081040: [top + 40] <- 0x2c9408e1b0d9; context
    0x7fff72081038: [top + 32] <- 0x2c9408e1b3d1; function
    0x7fff72081030: [top + 24] <- 0x2c9408e1b389 ; [sp + 40] 0x2c9408e1b389 <JS Function add>
    0x7fff72081028: [top + 16] <- 0x2c9408e1b2f9 ; [sp + 48] 0x2c9408e1b2f9 <JS Function addText>
    0x7fff72081020: [top + 8] <- 0x2c9408e1b341 ; [sp + 56] 0x2c9408e1b341 <JS Function addNumber>
    0x7fff72081018: [top + 0] <- 0 ; rbx (smi)
[deoptimizing: end 0x2c9408e1b3d1  => node=111, pc=0x23522b364aa0, state=NO_REGISTERS, alignment=no padding, took 0.076 ms]
[removing optimized code for: ]
[marking add 0x2c9408e1b388 for recompilation, reason: small function, ICs with typeinfo: 1/1 (100%)]
[optimizing: add / 2c9408e1b389 - took 0.013, 0.024, 0.000 ms]
Compiled: 4 functions with 939 byte source size in 0.599000ms.
[marking  0x2c9408e1b3d0 for recompilation, reason: hot and stable, ICs with typeinfo: 2/12 (16%)]
Inlined addNumber called from .
Inlined addText called from .
Inlined add called from .
Inlined add called from .
[optimizing:  / 2c9408e1b3d1 - took 0.100, 0.194, 0.000 ms]
Compiled: 5 functions with 1753 byte source size in 0.893000ms.
time2: 1759ms
```

The first loop gets deoptimised due to parameter change and runs longer. It cannot be explained by cache hit/miss because there are no read/writes.

Source:
http://floitsch.blogspot.in/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-inlining.html

Comment: +1 The guide on tracing the optimisation process was useful - I usually try and look at `--print-code` but it's difficult to see the difference at times without any annotations.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is about cache memory. in 1st, javascript dont know function '`add`' do what.
but in 2nd javascript understand that 'addNumber' return sum of x & y and '`addText`' return `x+''+y`

Comment: How does cache get into this. And why ?

Comment: sorry about my English ...
i said 'i think'...
java script in 'add' function, first try to add x & y as integer value. if type x & y is integer, return sum of them. but if one of them is not integer, return string of x + string of y.
when returned as integer, write in cache memory that: 'add' function return integer! and in next time, first try to return sum of inputs.
next time that x & y are not integer, its take time to change cache : 'add' function return string...